# Why do fbedev OGLES Draw Calls takes 30+us each?

Tags: pi-3b+, opengles

When operating with the framebuffer OpenGL Drivers on my HTC Vive, performance is incredibly good on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ EXCEPT that every single draw call takes anywhere from 30-50us, regardless of how much is being drawn.  I can combine draw calls and all, but it makes it very difficult for more sophisticated scenes, where I would need to alter uniforms between drawing geometry.

Are all draw calls across all Raspberry Pi OpenGL ES APIs insanely slow?  Is this a known issue with the framebuffer one?  Or is it possible there is something wrong with my setup?  Maybe my OpenGL ES Drivers are out of date?  (It is the newest Raspian)

I've asked this question here about a week ago and there was some back and forth but no answers.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216097